# Calling an API on Xamarin getting Bad Request

Tags: asp.net, rest, api, xamarin, xamarin.android

So, I'm new to Xamarin and I'm trying to call API. I didn't have any trouble when I want to get data from a wheather api. But when I try to call my own API which is created with ASP.NET RESTFull and help of internet.

So this is my code. I can get what I need when I use ;

```
http://localhost:1658/api/person
```

on my browser, it works perfectly. But when I use;

```
        string querystring = "http://10.0.2.2:1658/api/person";
        JContainer results = await GetDataFromService(querystring);
   }

    public static async Task<JContainer> GetDataFromService(string queryString)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.GetAsync(queryString);

        JContainer data = null;
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            data = (JContainer)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
        }

        return data;
    }
```

it didn't work.

This is my API codes:

```
       // This code piece in PersonController.cs
       // GET: api/Person
    public ArrayList Get()
    {
        PersonPersistance pp = new PersonPersistance();
        return pp.getPersons();

    }


        // This piece of code in PersonPersistance.cs
        public Person getPerson(long ID)
    {
        Person p = new Person();
        //MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader MSR = null;
        SqlDataReader MSR = null;
        string selectquery = "select * from person where Id="+ID.ToString();
        //MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(selectquery,conn);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectquery, conn);

        //MSR = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        MSR = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if(MSR.Read())
        {
            p.Id = MSR.GetInt32(0);
            p.FirstName = MSR.GetString(1);
            p.LastName = MSR.GetString(2);
            p.Pay = MSR.GetInt32(3);
            p.BeginDay = MSR.GetDateTime(4);
            p.EndDate = MSR.GetDateTime(5);
            return p;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Have your tried to pin this uri in your android device? I don't think there is problem with your code on your client side, it is possible that you passed a invalid uri here.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `await` to your `ReadAsStringAsync()`:

```
public static async Task<JContainer> GetDataFromService(string queryString)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var response = await client.GetAsync(queryString);

    JContainer data = null;
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JContainer>(json);
    }

    return data;
}
```